# React-map-gl dynamic geoJson file cause Error 414 - URI too long

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl, react-map-gl

I fetch the data from database which is not a geoJson, so I use array.map function dynamically making one base on the data I fetched, then passing to  component. But it seems this geoJson paste to URL as GET parameters...

if I save the geoJson as static file then import, it works.

How can I change the GET method to POST method in React-map-gl??

```
 <Source
  type="geojson"
  data={myData}
  ref={_sourceRef}
  >
 <Layer {...stopPointLayer} />
 </Source>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can identify the root cause here by looking at the source code for `uber/react-map-gl` and `mapbox/mapbox-gl-js`. When you pass `data={myData}` in your `Source` component, `/react-map-gl` relies on Mapbox's [`GeoJSONSource#setData`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/25d48f47db0449776479953d3d70cc97cf214299/src/source/geojson_source.js#L175-L199), as indicated in `src/components/source.js` [here](https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl/blob/68aa89d311f32008d49af1403f69fbabd07adec7/src/components/source.js#L114-L116):

```
if (type === 'geojson') {
  source.setData(sourceOptions.data);
}
```

As indicated in the [API reference for `setData`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#geojsonsource#setdata), the `data` argument must be a GeoJSON data object or a URL to one. It sounds like it might be the case that when you are passing `myData` dynamically, it might not be in the correct format, but it is when you configure it as a static file. I don't see a reason why the issue would be related to GET vs POST requests in this particular scenario.